SUM on dynamic filtered data
I am struggling with SUM / filtering on the attached sheet.
What I am actually searching for is the formula at the F25 cell.
The formula to expect is:

Cell D25 will contain a textual formatted date equal to $B$6 + 1 day
Date value can be derived using DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B6;".";"/")) for any formatted date cell
Cell F25 should contain the value $F$6 - "SUM(E17:E21) where B17:B21 before D25" (divided by 8, max 0)

In other words, subtract any E-column values where the B-column values are before the date in D25.
In my example, row 18 meets this criteria and should be subtracted, row 19 not.
I struggle with filtering the "B17:B21 before D25" part
Can you please help me create the proper filter for this?
SOLVED! UPDATE!! Thanks to the answer by @Codedabbler, I now have a workable solution;
=MAX(0; CEILING(($F$6-SUMIFS(E17:E23; MAP(B17:B23;LAMBDA(cellref; DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(cellref;".";"/")))); "<"&DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(D27;".";"/")))) / 8))



You can try this.  Replace:
SUM(E17)

in your formula with
=SUMIFS(E17:E21,B17:B21,"<"&D25)

The logic for this part of the formula is: sum range E17:E21 if value in corresponding row in range B17:B21 is less than value in D25.  As long as the dates are correctly formatted to dates, this should work.

You pointed me to the right direction with your answer! Thank you!
My next problem was converting the string date representations to date values. I used the MAP function for this. What seems to work for me now is:
=MAX(0; CEILING(($F$6-SUMIFS(E17:E23; MAP(B17:B23;LAMBDA(cellref; DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(cellref;".";"/")))); "<"&DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(D27;".";"/")))) / 8))

Glad that worked for you.  I would create a separate question for the second problem you are having.  I don't use a lot of lamda functions myself, but there are people on here that are very good and usually provide a fast response to Google Sheets formula questions.

=MAX(0; CEILING(($F$6-SUMIFS(E17:E23; MAP(B17:B23;LAMBDA(cellref; DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(cellref;".";"/")))); "<"&DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(D27;".";"/")))) / 8))

